# Обработка событий между компонентами

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть 2 компонента, в одном есть кнопка по клику происходит обработка события `@click="blockShow = !blockShow"`, в другом есть блок в котором `:class="{ show: blockShow }"`. Вопрос, как мне сделать, чтобы 2-ой блок видел `blockShow` и добавлялся класс `show`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В родительском компоненте (возможно приложении), создаем свойство `blockShow`:

```
data: {
 blockShow: false
}
```

Компоненту, который будет управлять статусом, назначаем `v-model` как `blockShow`:

```
<component1 v-model="blockShow"></component1>
```

Компоненту, который будет "слушать" статус, передаем `blockShow` как `props`:

```
<component2 :block-show="blockShow"></component2>
```

И в компоненте, который управляет статусом реализуем `v-model` по принципу, описанному в официальном руководстве Vue - [Использование v-model на компонентах](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-v-model-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85), т.е.

```js
const component1 = Vue.component('Component1', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      status: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleStatus() {
      this.model = !this.model
      this.$emit('input', this.model)
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="box">
    <div>Компонент 1</div>
    <button type="button" @click="toggleStatus">Изменить статус</button>
  </div>
  `
})

const component2 = Vue.component('Component2', {
  props: {
    blockShow: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="box">
    <div>Компонент 2</div>
    <div v-if="blockShow" :class="[{ show: blockShow }]">
      {{ blockShow }}
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blockShow: false
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}

.show {
  background: #42b983;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component1 v-model="blockShow"></component1>
  <component2 :block-show="blockShow"></component2>
</div>
```